# Rails 4 Active record, find object by checking serialized array attribute for inclusion in another array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

I have a model which has a serialized attribute ids.

```
Model A {
    serialize :ids, JSON
}
```

This attribute is used to store a list of IDS [1,2]. How can I search for objects where the list of IDS are a subset of another list of IDS?

I know this would be possible if A.ids would have had a singular value. In which case I could have used this:

```
A.where(ids: [1,2,3])
```

to find all object which have an id that is included in [1,2,3]. But how do I achieve something similar now that A.ids are an array of values?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I had to rethink the database instead. You can't win them all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `A.ids` returns an array of arrays with ids,you can use [Array#flatten](http://apidock.com/ruby/Array/flatten).

```
[ 4, 5, 6, [7, 8] ].flatten
#=> [4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```